# Filling in NAs in data in R by id

Tags: r

I am having a little problem "filling in gaps". It's not a missing data question, it's more about merging but it's not working great.

So, my data looks like this

```
id        name         region   Company
1        John Smith     West    Walmart
1        John Smith     West    Amazon
1        John Smith
1        John Smith     West    P&G
2        Jane Smith     South   Apple
2        Jane Smith      
3      Richard Burkett      
3      Richard Burkett  West   Walmart
```

And so on. 
What I want to do is fill in those gaps in the region variable by their id. So, id 1, John Smith, on the third row, should have West in the third column. Jane Smith's region should be filled in "South" where it is missing.

I've tried creating a separate dataset and then merging it based on id but it creates duplicate rows and basically increases the N by something like 14 times (no idea why).

```
region1<-subset(df1, df1$region=="DC"| df1$region=="Midwest"|df1$region=="Northeast"|df1$region=="South"|df1$region=="West")
region<-region1[,c(id","region")]
df2<-merge(df1, region, by="id")
```

I've checked the structure of the variables. Id variable is interval and region is a factor. I think there should be a super simple way to do this but I'm just not getting it. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `dplyr::arrange` followed by `tidyr::fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3), 
      name=c(rep("John Smith",4), rep("Jane Smith", 2), rep("Richard Burkett", 2)), 
      region=c("West", "West", NA, "West", "South",NA, "West", NA),     
      Company=c("Walmart","Amazon",NA,"P&G","Apple",NA,"Walmart",NA)) %>%
arrange(id, name) %>%
fill(region)
```

Results in:

```
  id            name region Company
1  1      John Smith   West Walmart
2  1      John Smith   West  Amazon
3  1      John Smith   West      NA
4  1      John Smith   West     P&G
5  2      Jane Smith  South   Apple
6  2      Jane Smith  South      NA
7  3 Richard Burkett   West Walmart
8  3 Richard Burkett   West      NA
```

Comment: I am not interested in filling in Company and these four variables are not the only variables that I have in the dataset (in fact, I have 137 variables) so I can't type them all up using arrange and fill. When I try to use your code just for the variables that I am interested in, it says `> df2<-arrange(df1$id) %>%
+   fill(df1$region)
Error in UseMethod("arrange_") : 
  no applicable method for 'arrange_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')`

Comment: Arrange should stay the same. It's just there to order by the id and name (which appears to be redundant anyway). How do you know which variables you want to apply this to and which ones you don't?

Comment: I just want to apply it to region. I have cleaned all the other variables and this is the last one!

Answer (score 2):

Here´s an R base solution. Suppose your data.frame is `df`

```
regions <- sapply(split(df$region, df$id), function(x) {
  ind <- is.na(x);
  x[ind] <- x[!ind][1];
  x
})

df$region <- unlist(regions)
df
  id            name region Company
1  1      John Smith   West Walmart
2  1      John Smith   West  Amazon
3  1      John Smith   West    <NA>
4  1      John Smith   West     P&G
5  2      Jane Smith  South   Apple
6  2      Jane Smith  South    <NA>
7  3 Richard Burkett   West Walmart
8  3 Richard Burkett   West    <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution which should work is `group_by` on `id` and then `fill`. Ideally the solution which should work in OP condition should cover in `both` direction.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
fill(region) %>%
fill(region, .direction = "up")

#     id name            region Company
#  <int> <chr>           <chr>  <chr>  
#1     1 John Smith      West   Walmart
#2     1 John Smith      West   Amazon 
#3     1 John Smith      West   <NA>   
#4     1 John Smith      West   P&G    
#5     2 Jane Smith      South  Apple  
#6     2 Jane Smith      South  <NA>   
#7     3 Richard Burkett West   Walmart
#8     3 Richard Burkett West   <NA>
```

Data

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), name = c("John Smith", 
"John Smith", "John Smith", "John Smith", "Jane Smith", "Jane Smith", 
"Richard Burkett", "Richard Burkett"), region = c("West", "West", 
NA, "West", "South", NA, "West", NA), Company = c("Walmart", 
"Amazon", NA, "P&G", "Apple", NA, "Walmart", NA)), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "region", "Company"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```